# Symbolic vs word operators eg ( '||' vs 'or' and '!' vs 'not')

Tags: c++

I think `or` is keyword in c++.

It might be that I've been doing too much python code recently but I find `or` is more readable than `||` and `xor` much more readable than `^`.

Is it a good idea to use the word alternatives to the symbolic operators?
Why don't I see them used more?

Comment: I did this, switching from Pascal to C a million years ago.  Big project too.  The guy that ended up maintaining it hated me with a blinding passion.  He never got more than half done fixing it.  Can't blame him, it *was* a big mistake.

Comment: @Hans: Eh? `sed -i 's/\band\b/\&\&/g; s/\bor\b/||/g' *`

Comment: See [C alternative tokens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_alternative_tokens)

Comment: @FredNurk But then you end up with things like `printf("Your password must contain lowercase && uppercase letters, digits, && punctuation.\n");`

Comment: Since `&&` is also used to represent an rvalue function parameter now, using `and` (and `or` for consistency) would be less confusing for people first beginning to code. It's also easier on the eyes, in my opinion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it a good idea to use the word alternatives to the symbolic operators?

Completely depends on the target audience for your code ­– both people and tools.  People can be unused to them, and some tools don't recognize them.  (Sometimes those tools use <ciso646> to define them as macros.)

I've started to use "and" and "or" more, especially when switching between C++ and Python, and it has been more readable.  The bit of extra consistency between languages matters more than I first thought it would, but more importantly, && and || are **control structures and not operators** (i.e. short-circuiting), thus making them words differentiates from operators.

(Yes, technically they're operators in C++, but they're more similar to if, else, return, while, and so forth than +, -, *, and other operators.  The comma and conditional operators are similarly control structures, and it probably isn't a coincidence they are often found confusing, or at least less readable than separate statements and if/else, respectively.)

However, I very rarely use them in new code written for SO, for example, because I've not yet encountered a question where bringing up this side issue was more important than being readable to SO's C++ audience.

Comment: All coding conventions I know of would consider using e.g. 'or' instead of || a bad idea. Use 'or' in Python, || in C and C++, period.

Answer (score 9):

The unsatisfying answer is that you should use symbolic operators because everyone else does.

An arguably more sensible reason is that they stand out more from the rest of the code.

Comment: Though standing out as words, similar to if, else, etc., can be [beneficial too](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4672934), especially with an editor that highlights them as keywords (which it should, for C++).

Answer (score 8):

Every C++ programmer knows about `&&` and `||`.

Not every C++ programmer is aware that `and` and `or` are legal alternatives.

For that reason alone, you're better off sticking with what's commonly used.

It is pretty easy to get used to, so I'd say it's not a big deal, and definitely not worth potentially confusing the reader of your code over.

Comment: Unless you know. It's not obvious that and => && (this could be `and and`). My argument is that the mapping could be and => &. Without knwoing or research it is confusing.

Comment: @Martin: I don't buy that argument.  Without knowing or research, you're lost about what -> means in C++.  That's no reason not to use ->.  Is C++ complex?  If we could redo history would we provide only one way to spell logical-and?  Yes and yes, unquestionably, but us the majority are in no position to change those; yet understanding "and" isn't hard and should take less than 5 minutes if you already understand "&&".

Comment: @martin: I think it's more likely that people just plain don't know that `and` and `or` are keywords in the first place. And then they're going to try to hunt down a macro something that can make sense of this unknown syntax. As far as the people who do know about the existence of those keywords, I'd assume that they also know what they *mean*.

Answer (score 7):

These keywords are **alternative tokens** which were added to the standard (Standard C) in 1995. See details here
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_alternative_tokens

Why the keywords were added:

> The alternative tokens allow programmers to use C language bitwise and logical operators which could otherwise be hard to type on some international and non-QWERTY keyboards.

How they were added:

> They are implemented as a group of macro constants in the C standard library in the `iso646.h` header.

The `iso646.h` header defines 11 macros including `or`.

What about C++:

> The above-mentioned identifiers are operator keywords in the `ISO C++ programming language` and do not require the inclusion of a header file. For consistency, the `C++98 standard` provides the header `<ciso646>`. However the latter file has no effect, being empty.

So, there is a historic reason for having the keywords in C/C++ languages, and it is not related to what is better to use. As mentioned above, you should stick to a coding convention.

Comment: Upvoted for historical data and rationales not posted elsewhere. Nice work.

Answer (score 4):

My first question is `or` a `bit-wise or |` or a `Boolean shortcut or ||`?

I bet there is half a dozen people on my team that would have to go look it up.

So I think it is better to stick with the standard convention,
Because that is what people are used to. The whole point of programming is to not be ambiguous.

Comment: +1 - I was unaware it was even allowable, and then had to read the other answers thourougly to figure out which one it probably was. Not obvious at all. In fact, if it were *me*, I would be tempted to make it a separate operator that performs a non-short-circuiting boolean or.

Comment: bitor, bitand, and compl are the alternatives for bitwise tokens

Answer (score 1):

These keywords are only there for terminals that can't handle the special characters `|`, `&` etc. Whether they constitute a more readable code or not is arguable.

If you know what `||` means then `or` is not more readable than `||`. And if you know the very fundamentals of C++, i.e. the syntax, then in my humble opinion one is not more readable than the other.

Also, C++ programmers in most cases use the special-character alternatives of the keywords. So it's usually a good idea not to be the exception in a project, unless you're starting a project and you're setting the rules.

Comment: More space and typing is arguable too: shift-7 shift-7 isn't easier (nor harder) for me than a-n-d, "or" isn't shorter than "||", etc.

Comment: Err...no. `||` is the same number of characters. Even if it weren't, "number of charcters" is a pretty lame argument. If that mattered, then it would logically follow that we should get rid of *all* the English keywords (`cost`, `static`, etc) in favor of sybmols (`¢`, and `$`?).

Comment: Thanks, edited. Maybe I should just say that if you find `||` "unreadable" then you shouldn't be coding in C++ (or C for that matter).`

Comment: I'd agree with that. In fact, it was the gist of my answer.

Answer (score -3):

`||` is how you say "boolean or" in C++. If you actually write `or` you are going to confuse the heck out of readers of your code, even if you can get the compiler to accept it.

I really do have sympathy for your argument, deft. Honestly. C++ code is really ugly (and IMHO hard to follow) due to its reliance on line-noise-like symbology. But that's the C++ philosophy. If you want nice Englishy reable code, *C++ is just not your language*. Try [Ada](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ada/info).

I'm serious here. In a lot of ways Ada is a better language. This is one of them. But if you are going to stick with C++ instead, you need to ebrace it. Trying to write Ada (or Pascal) in C++ is no better than trying to write C++ or Fortran in Ada.

Comment: How about we switch `sizeof` to a unary `$` and the new `alignof` to a unary `@`.  The only reason `||` means "boolean or" is because it means that in C.  I would never use `bitor` or `and_eq` because the symbolic versions convey more info.  But `or` means "boolean or" by default.

Comment: @deft_code - I'm not arguing your logic one bit, deft. In fact, I made a nearly identical comment to another answer. Its just that is **not** the C++ way, and never will be. If that's the way you think, you'd be far happier philosophically with a language like Ada.