# Are the integer comparison operators short circuited in C++?

Tags: c++, comparison, short-circuiting

Like the title states, are the integer (or any numerical datatypes like float etc.) comparison operators (==, !=, >, >=, <, <=) short circuited in C++?

Comment: In what way? Do you mean if those are chained with boolean comparisons like `&&` and `||`?

Comment: You mean like in 12 < x < 15? Because you can't do that in C++. And I can't see any other way to consider them to be short circuited

Comment: The funny thing is that you explained in the detail any part of the question (what you mean by integers, what comparison operators are), but what _short circuited_ mean. What is it?

Comment: @peoro: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: && and || are [control structures](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4672934), thinking of them similarly to comparison operators will confuse you.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: did the OP mean that? I thought it was unlikely that out could wonder if `==` can be a short circuit operator; was rather thinking that OP might mean something like `12<x<15` in klez example.

Comment: @peoro It's a possibility. The way the question is phrased, it seems like he really does. That's all we can go on, and without further clarification that is what I will respond to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They can't short circuit. To know if `x == y`, `x != y`, etc are `true` or `false` you need to evaluate both, x and y. Short circuiting refers to logical boolean operators `&&` and `||`. Logical AND is known to be false if the first argument is false and Logical OR is known to be true if the first argument is true. In these cases you don't need to evaluate the second argument, this is called short circuiting.

**Edit:** this follows the discussions for why `x >= y` don't short circuit when the operands are unsigned ints and `x` is zero:

For logical operands short circuiting comes for free and is implementation neutral. The machine code for `if(f() && g()) stmt;` is likely to look similar to this:

```
call f
test return value of f
jump to next on zero
call g
test return value of g
jump to next on zero
execute stmt
next: ...
```

To prevent short circuiting you actually *need to do the computation of the result of the operator and test it after that*. This takes you a register and makes the code less efficient.

For non-logical operators the situation is the opposite. Mandating short circuiting implies:

- The compiler can't choose an evaluation of the expression that uses a minimum number of registers.
- The semantics may be implementation defined (or even undefined) for many cases, like when comparing with maximum value.
- The compiler needs to add an additional test/jump. For `if(f() > g()) stmt;` the machine code will look like this:

  ```
  call f
  mov return value of f to R1
  test return value of f
  jump to next on zero
  call g
  compare R1 with return value of g
  jump to next on less-than equal
  execute stmt
  next: ...
  ```

  Note how the first test and jump are just unnecessary otherwise.

Comment: Technically, `<` and `>` *can* be short-circuited (lazily evaluated) for some values of fixed-size integer types. Still, +1.

Comment: @larsmans: This would only be done as an optimisation in C++ implementations, partially because from the POV of the standard, there is only one fixed-size integer type (`char`). All the others are implementation-defined (restricted only by relative width).

Comment: They are all fixed-size, the standard just doesn't specify the size (only that there has to be one and how to obtain it).

Comment: @larsman right. But still the order of evaluation of operands is unspecified and the compiler should evaluate both of them to prevent implementation specific surprises.

Comment: And `==` can be short-circuited for floating types when the LHS is a NaN. Also not worth the confusion that would be introduced by conditionally not evaluating the RHS.

Comment: @Tomalak: "Fixed-size" led you astray here: it's a fixed range that matters for what larsmans mentions, and char's range is implementation-defined too.

Comment: @FredNurk: Yes, indeed. Well spotted. However, my point remains unaffected. :)

Comment: @ybungalowbill: but the order of operand evaluation need not be unspecified; for `&&` and `||`, it's left to right. This is exactly what Kernighan fulminated against in Pascal (http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/bwk-on-pascal.html). @Steve Jessop: isn't it confusion just because we're used to current behavior? Why are we not confused by short-circuited boolean evaluation?

Comment: @larsmans: Because we already think of && and || as [control structures](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4672934) rather than as (boolean) numerical operators.

Comment: Re the edit: I think you meant x <= y and x is zero (or keep x >= y and say y is zero, of course).

Comment: @Fred: basically depends on your assembly language, in x86 what I wrote is correct (`cmp` subtracts second operand from the first and sets the flags accordingly).

Comment: @ybungalobill: No, it doesn't.  Given x >= y for unsigneds, if x is zero, you must still look at y; but given x <= y when x is zero, you know it's always true and could short-circuit both the y evaluation and the compare (if the language allowed such).

Comment: @Fred: In our case it's given x we check x > y (**strong** inequality), so if x is zero we short circuit (jump to next). Otherwise, we execute stmt when x > y, so we don't execute it when x <= y (it's the negation of the condition), so we jump to next if the result of the comparison is x <= y.

Answer (score 1):

No. The comparison operators require both operands to evaluate the correct answer. By contrast, the logical operators `&&` and `||` in some cases don't need to evaluate the right operand to get the right answer, and therefore do "short-circuit".

Answer (score 1):

No, how could they be. In order to check whether `1 == 2` you have to inspect both the 1 and the 2. (Ofcoruse, a compiler can do a lot of reordering, static checking, optimizations, etc. but that's not inherit to c++)

Answer (score 1):

How would that work? Short-circuiting means you can avoid evaluating the RHS based solely on the result of evaluating the LHS.

e.g.

```
true || false
```

doesn't need to evaluate the RHS because `true || x` is `true` no matter what `x` turns out to be.

But this won't work for any of the comparisons that you list. For example:

```
5 == x
```

How can you ever know the result of the expression without knowing `x`?

Comment: `0 > x` is always false for `unsigned x`. (I didn't downvote, btw.)

Comment: @larsmans: As I pointed out in my comment on the same topic in your answer, the C++ standard could never mandate that as the integral type ranges are all implementation-defined (though, mathematically speaking, your logic is of course sound).

Comment: @Tomalak: that's nonsense. All type ranges are specified abstractly as, e.g. [`INT_MIN`, `INT_MAX`] for `signed int` and [0, `UINT_MAX`] for `unsigned int`. It's not my answer btw.

Comment: @larsmans: Yea actually I guess the lowerbound for `unsigned int` is likely mandated. OK, well another approach to this is that it would be highly eccentric of the language to allow short-circuiting just for that one edge case, but not for others. It would get very confusing considering which comparisons have side-effects and which don't. :)